# What can I use to build a short retaining wall for a patio extension?

Tags: retaining-wall

We want to extend our patio that is currently about 10 x 5 feet to about 10 x 10 feet.

Problem is there is a slope where the current patio ends. The next 5 feet has an approx. 1 foot deep slope.

My worry is that if I build a retaining wall and compact the newly filled slope, the compaction will destroy the retaining wall.

What would be a strong enough material that can withhold the compaction and the 1 foot deep filling?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems like a prime job for a concrete wall. Of course it would need to bear on footings below frost depth. Is there some reason that's not suitable?

Comment: @isherwood Isn't that a *bit* overkill for a wall that will be 1 foot tall?

Comment: I would argue that a concrete wall would be too much of an overkill.

Comment: Well, you've expressed concern about compaction, and you haven't posted a photo, so that's the only reliable advice I can offer.

Comment: A photo of the place the wall would go would be more useful. Might wanna mow first.

Comment: How about a timber based retaining wall with dead man?

Comment: lol I know I'll mow and resend

Answer (score 2):

Retaining wall block is made to have heavily compacted backfill. Some of it, if not all of it would have to be crushed stone though. After that patio pavers would probably be more forgiving of any future ground movement than poured concrete, but it all depends.

A wooden deck patio extension might be the easiest way to go.

Comment: How about a timber based retaining wall with dead man?

Comment: After seeing your pic, that's a tough one. Another 5' out and you're almost right against the fence? Not to talk you out of it, but that's some nice looking grass! Hahaha

Comment: because of the slope it looks like the fence is very close. I want to add 3 more rows of those slabs and that will only be half way to the fence, 3-4 feet away.

Comment: Can you pick those slabs up or are they mortared down? If you can pick them up, what's under them?

Comment: Yes, I can pick them up, there is leveling sand under them and probably undisturbed soil under that.

Comment: I'm thinking of building a timber retaining wall that is a foot tall plus about 6 inches in the ground. The wall will have 3 sides. I remove the current slabs, fill up the hole and compact the whole area together. In the end put the slabs down.

Comment: I'm also planning to use dead man and rebar to strengthen the wall.

Comment: L4z10w - Sounds like a good compromised plan. It's probably not going to  last 100 years, but you don't need it to. If you don't already have one, get a small laser level. Keep it level left and right with a slight pitch towards the fence for water run off. Good luck!